# DJI on board sdk for obstacle avoidance

Tags: dji-sdk

Using DJI onboard sdk, I want to avoid obstacles during flight controller mode. To achieve this I have few questions
1.  Can I update waypoints at runtime without pausing current mission? 
2.  Can I add new setpoint at runtime when waypoint mission is in progress? If yes what will be state of waypoint mission in progress?
3.  Can I change current altitude by changing vertical Velocity (Vz)? If I change velocity while mission in progress does mission stops or continues with updated velocity?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change the behavior of the UAV mid-mission you will need to use your mobile device via DJI Go4 or MSDK in coordination with the OSDK.  The OSDK loads your mission to the onboard computer pre-flight, whereas the mobile device can interact during flight.  For me reading go to DJI Documentation: [OSDK Missions](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-missions.html) and [Mobile - Onboard Communication](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-mobile-communication.html)